# Put a slider into responsive mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive

Can you please help with some jquery tips ?
I tried to make this slider ( https://www.jqueryscript.net/slider/Fully-Responsive-Flexible-jQuery-Carousel-Plugin-slick.html ) into a responsive one, but I don't know why, when I reduce the window, practicly everything is okay, but when I make the window bigger, the slider disapear.

Check my code :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        <!-- écouteur sur le bouton burger 
        -->
        $('#btn-burger').click(function() {
            $('nav ul').toggle();
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.demo').slick()
        });
        $('.demo').slick({
        mobileFirst:true,
            responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 3,
      infinite: true
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 769,
    settings: {
      slidesToShow: 2,
      dots: true
    }
  }, {
    breakpoint: 469,
    settings: "unslick"
  }]

        })
            
    </script>
```

I have to finish my website before Thursday, thank you for helping me !

Bianca

Comment: no instructions after 1024px ?

Comment: Which instructions should I put ?

Comment: did you had read the documentation related to your plugin ? aka => https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/ Go always to the source, never lost your self in "subsourcing" Good read

Comment: I'll read that ! Thank you !